# VK api photos.getAlbums не возвращает ID альбома

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю запрос  в ВК апи что бы получить список всех альбомов.
Данные приходят все что должны прийти кроме `ID` альбома что очень важно в мое случае.
что делал может кто сталкивался с этим?

запрос к апи.

```
@GET("photos.getAlbums")
Observable<AlbumsResponce> getAlbums(@Query("owner_id") String ownerId,
                                     @Query("need_covers") int needCovers,
                                     @Query("access_token") String accessToken,
                                     @Query("photo_sizes") int needPhotoSizes);
```

получения данных и вывод в логи:

```
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext ");
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getId()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getId());
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getThumbId()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getThumbId());
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getOwnerId()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getOwnerId());
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getDescription()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getDescription());
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getTitle()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getTitle());
Log.e("AlbumsPresenter", "onNext albumsResponce get(0).getSizes().get(0).getSrc()()"+albumsResponce.getResponse().get(0).getSizes().get(0).getSrc());
```

результат в консоли:

```
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext 
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getId()0
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getThumbId()431783953
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getOwnerId()384281022
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getDescription()888888888888888888
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getTitle()8888888888888888888
E/AlbumsPresenter: onNext albumsResponce get(0).getSizes().get(0).getSrc()()https://pp.vk.me/c622926/v622926353/21ba5/8uK9JEFMF90.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема.
в документации Вконтакте написано что ID альбома будет называться в ответе "id".
Но ответе от апи это поле называется "aid"